# replace text between specific occurrence of delimiter only if it's blank - bash

Tags: bash, unix

Dears,

In the below string "|" is the delimiter in the file. If date between 19th and 20th occurrence is blank than replace it with the current date for all the lines in the file.

```
227354|SD-PD-100456|P-OD-98767318712|ABC|O|EN|UJ|NM|ABC|ABC;ABC;ABC||98765432||I|A||01/04/2019||||06/04/2020||JU|HINB
```

```
sed -i "s/\(\([^|]*|\)\{19\}\)[^|]*/\1$(date '+%d\/%m\/%Y')/g" *
```

by using this command I am able to replace text between 19th and 20th delimiter, however I don't understand how I can only replace if it's blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is more suitable for this job:

```
awk -v dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y') 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} $20 == ""{$20=dt} 1' file
```

```
227354|SD-PD-100456|P-OD-98767318712|ABC|O|EN|UJ|NM|ABC|ABC;ABC;ABC||98765432||I|A||01/04/2019|||09/04/2020|06/04/2020||JU|HINB
```

**Details:**

- `-v dt=$(date '+%d/%m/%Y')`: Send `date` as command line argument to `awk` in variable `dt`
- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}`: Sets `|` as input and output delimiters
- `$20 == ""`: If column 20 is empty
- `{$20=dt}`: Sets value of `$20` to variable `dt`
- `1`: Default action to print a row

Comment: Thanks a lot Anubhava for the solution and explanation. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in a blank, then look for a blank:

```
sed -i "s/\(\([^|]*|\)\{19\}\)|/\1$(date '+%d\/%m\/%Y')|/" filename
```

Comment: Thanks Beta for the feedback.